# React native. Back button redirect to the Home page

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a tab with multiple components

```
const HomePageStack = createStackNavigator();
const HomePageScreen = () => (
    <HomePageStack.Navigator initialRouteName='Главная' screenOptions={{ headerShown: true, headerTransparent: true, headerTintColor: '#fff', headerTitleStyle: { color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' }, }}>
        <HomePageStack.Screen name='Главная' component={Home} options={{ title: "Главная" }} style={{ height: '100%' }} />
        <HomePageStack.Screen name='Рецепт' component={Recipe} option={{ title: 'Рецепт' }} style={{ height: '100%' }} />
        <HomePageStack.Screen name='Аккаунт' component={Account} option={{ title: 'Аккаунт' }} style={{ height: '100%' }} />
    </HomePageStack.Navigator>
)
```

When checking, I go this way (using navigation.navigate with data)

**Home -> Recipe -> Account -> Recipe**

Back Button works fine until I switch to the Recipe a second time

When I go to the Recipe for the second time and click back button, I am sent to the main page, but I want to be in the **Account**

*I have not customized or changed how the back button works.*

Redirect function (from Account to Recipe 2):

```
const handleRecipe = (_id) => {
    navigation.navigate('Рецепт', { _id })
}
```

*I want the back button to work as expected and redirect the user to the Account and not to the Home page. I suspect the problem is with my redirect function.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigate` pops back to earlier in the stack because the `Recipe` screen is already present there. To push another instance of `Recipe` on the navigation stack you can use the push action instead. So on the `Account` screen you use the push action instead of the navigate action to avoid going back to the already present `Recipe` screen. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#push for an example.

Comment: Thanks, everything works well now